# Woocommerce API endpoint saying: Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this resource

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I am using the WooCommerce API endpoint for updating a order status to "completed" but I get this error:

Error: Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this resource
I am using the new WC API version 1 (and not the old legacy WordPress API versions 2 or 3).

I use this:

```
$woocommerce = new Client(
    'https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dk/', 
    'ck_xxxxxxxxxx', 
    'cs_xxxxxxxxxx',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v1',
    ]
);

$data = [
    'status' => 'completed'
];

print_r($woocommerce->put('orders/5490', $data));
```

I have checked that the API key in WooCommerce has "read/write" permissions and that the user connected to the API key is an admin (if that has anything to say).

I am using HTTPS / SSL.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution and it is working :-)

I inserted this into .htaccees in the start of the rewrite block:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

And now it is not giving the error :-)